# Selenium Failed to start firefox browser on server with Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, pyvirtualdisplay

I run simple selenium code on my linux server but it return that error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Failed to start browser:
other os error
```

My python selenium code is this-

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.google.com')
browser.save_screenshot('screenie.png')
browser.quit()

display.stop()
```

And I also used firefox headless code but it return same error.

Comment: If you are using selenium 3 then you will have to download geckodriver and have to specify its path when creating firefox driver.

Comment: hey @sjethvani I also specify geckodriver but it return same error.

Comment: check the browser version as well. It should be less than 48.0 version

Comment: This error occurs also when your disk space is low.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using `Display` from `pyvirtualdisplay` you need to download the *GeckoDriver* binary from this [site](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases), place it anywhere within your system and explicitly mention the location of the *GeckoDriver* binary as per the following line of code to initiate the *Web Browser Client* :

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\geckodriver.exe')
```

Comment: you can also place geckodriver anywhere on your PATH and not worry about specifying the location in code.  This also has nothing to do with pyvirtualdisplay.